# mySQL: order by Parent and Child according to Weight

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a "category" table like this:

```
    +------+---------++---------+
    | id   | parent  || weight  |
    +------+---------++---------+
    |  1   |    0    ||   0     |
    |  2   |    1    ||   -1    |
    |  3   |    1    ||   -2    |
    |  4   |    2    ||   0     |
    |  5   |    1    ||   1     |
    |  6   |    5    ||   0     |
    |  7   |    5    ||   1     |
    +------+---------++---------+
```

How can I `ORDER BY` and `SELECT` statement to get the order like this:

```
1 5 7 6 2 4 3
```

in the first level every category in main branch (parent=1) get the order by their weights, while they have their children behinds. 
thank You and sorry for my eng

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add expected output in formatted table (text), as you have added the sample input data.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using (e.g. `5.7`, `8`) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)